# Angular directive not working with this code

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive

I must be missing something but I can't figure out why this directive is not showing up, is there anyone to help?

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<p>Test is <b>{{name}}</b> with myValue <b>{{myValue}}</b></p>
<my-new-directive my-test="{{myValue}}"></my-new-directive>
</body>

var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.name = 'World';
$scope.myValue = true;
});


app.directive('myNewDirective', function() {
return {
 restrict: 'E',
 replace: true,
 link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    attrs.$observe('myTest', function() {
    scope.name = attrs.myTest;
    if (!attrs.myTest) {
      this.template = '<div>FALSE</div>';
    } else {
      this.template = '<div>TRUE</div>';
    }
    scope.$apply();
  });
}
};
});
```

http://embed.plnkr.co/zijm24/preview

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't return template from the link function.

You can do this:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.myValue = true;
});


app.directive('myNewDirective', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      transclude: true,
      template: '<div>{{val}}</div>',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        attrs.$observe('myTest', function() {
          scope.name = attrs.myTest;
          if (!angular.fromJson(attrs.myTest)) {
            scope.val= 'FALSE';
          } else {
            scope.val= 'TRUE';
          }
          scope.$apply();
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

Comment: Now, I'm trying to do something similar with templateUrl but myValue would be the result of a service call. Any idea how I can achieve that? Need an Angular for dummies course sure :-(

Comment: For templateUrl you just replace the template attribute with templateUrl attribute:   templateUrl: 'template.html'   

As for the service, once you have a service that return a value, and you update myValue on the scope, the template acts accordingly. You don't need to change the directive implementation at all.

Comment: I strongly recommend egghead lessons: https://egghead.io/articles/new-to-angularjs-start-learning-here

Comment: Well, nope :-( does not work with templateUrl  http://plnkr.co/edit/zijm24?p=preview

Comment: No, it doesn't work that way. You can't use curly brackets for templateUrl. You should point to a predefined html, and in that html you should put the content that you had in your template ('<div>{{val}}</div>'). If you really insist on dynamically load different html according to scope values, I'm almost sure I have somewhere example for it, but first you have to convince yourself that you really need it...

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit misleading. In fact, my template is quite complex and probably better to put in an html file. Basically, it's for showing a form, depending on current element belongs to a user I want to show him a facility. The thing is that I'm able to do that already     templateUrl: function ($node, tattrs) {
    if(tattrs.userid != '' || tattrs.userid == null)
           return 'user_actions_button.html';
          else
           return 'my_form.html';
         }

Comment: well basically it's about adding different content depending on scope variables

Comment: If you want to add different content to a directive template depending on scope variable you need to manually `$compile` the content, attach it to the directive's scope, and finally append it to the directive template. There are many questions that cover how to do this on stackoverflow. But have you considered simply using `ngIf`/`ngShow`/`ngSwitch` to show different parts of your template depending on scope variables?

Comment: Ok so, I managed to make it work using the text binding prefix
you can see it in action there: http://plnkr.co/edit/zijm24?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

I would reduce this to this code:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Test is <b>{{name}}</b> with myValue <b>{{myValue}}</b></p>
    <label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="myValue"> myValue</label>
    <my-new-directive my-test="myValue"></my-new-directive>
</body>
```

Note that in the above HTML, `my-test` receives the model directly, not an expression. Also, I added a demo consisting of a checkbox so you can toggle the value.

Then, the JS would look like this for what you seem to need:

```
app.directive('myNewDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            name: '=myTest'
        },
        template: '<div>{{ name }}</div>'
    };
});
```

So basically, I removed transclusion, since you didn't use it (re-add if needed) and introduced a two-way bound isolate scope instead of manually adding the logic for observing the value of the parent scope's model. This lets you get rid of the linking function completely - at least until you need to add extra functionality.